# #Define and Variables in Swift

Tags: objective-c, variables, swift

Trying to use `#define` which Swift doesn't recognize. Question was answered easily, I'll leave this on here for future reference just in case someone needs it

```
//PrefsString.h    

#define PREFS [FISettings sharedSettings]


@interface FISettings : MYSSharedSettings
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *authToken;
```

to create the variable : `authToken`

which I use to store data so the user can login:

```
//SomeOtherView.m

PREFS.authToken = user.storeInfoString;
```

Comment: I assume you changes the build settings also to go with the bridging header?

Comment: Swift doesn't know about `#define`s. You have to make a global variable named `PREFS` instead. Or just use `FISettings.sharedSettings().authToken = ...`

Comment: Or use `let PREFS = FISettings.sharedSettings()` in Swift directly.

Comment: This isn't swift, where is the swift code?

Comment: sorry if it wasn't clear. The objective c code above is what I was using through a bridging header. codester and  fluidsonic were able to answer my questions which that you can't use @define

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per swift progamming [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_20)

> “In Swift, you can use functions and generics to achieve the same results [as complex macros] without any compromises. Therefore, the
>   complex macros that are in C and Objective-C source files are not made
>   available to your Swift code.”

So you can not use your macros in swift code.You should make this as utility function and use in swift code.